# Example 3.8 in Awodey's Category Theory

Tags: category-theory, equivalence-relations

Here is the Example 3.8:

[image]

What I don't understand is how the equivalence relation is constructed. I appreciate it if someone here can help me clear this painfully written example by Awodey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natural deduction inference rules from logic such as $i_2$ above are not arrows strictly speaking, for example, you have 2 *different* proofs for arrow $q: \psi \rightarrow \theta$ simply when $\theta=\psi$. You can prove via detour of applying $[p,q]$ (disjunction elimination ) after $i_2$ (disjunction introduction), but you can also directly use reiteration rule or even law of excluded middle to arrive at same conclusion. So without defining additional equivalence relation, equation (3.3) cannot hold which is required to further define coproduct objects. Once we mentally identify different but equivalent proofs, then equation (3.3) or (3.4) makes unique sense (like up to isomorphism) and thus strictly holds.

Category theory is all about spotting [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property), and usually we need to add some equivalence relation to achieve so.

Comment: So what happened was the arrow is replaced with a collection of proofs from a formula $\psi$ to $\theta$, and so a new category of proofs is defined?

Comment: @ShuichiSaihara it should be stated as "same effectful proofs are identified (replaced) by a same arrow", so a formal deductive system can be regarded as a *category* of proofs where formula/sentences are objects and the above (quotient) proofs are arrows between objects, and clearly such mentally constructed arrows compose...

Comment: I think I kind of understand it now. Can I say it like this? "Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be formulas. If there is a deduction from $\phi$ to $\psi$, then we define an arrow $p:\phi\longrightarrow\psi$." Is this right?

Comment: @ShuichiSaihara yes, you got it. And such an arrow $p$ is well defined and unique in above equivalence relation sense for coproduct construction purpose of your textbook.